# jQuery list refresh after ajax update

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am making a plugin which sends request via ajax.
This plugin changes ul elements via ajax. My parameters  are based on this list.
I am using jQuery version  2

Now I have the following function

```
   function getAgentList(){
    var lista = new Array();
    jQuery('div#aList li div.alListElement').each(function(){
        lista.push(jQuery(this).attr('data-aid'));
    });
    setData('agentList',lista);
}
```

function setdata add data by jQuery.data();

I don't know how can I get new list after other script's ajax updates my list.

When I use

```
jQuery.ajaxStop(function(){
getAgentList();
});
```

my parameters are the same .

Thanks in advance for any suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

are you shure your new elements fit the selector "div#aList li div.alListElement", try just "div#aList li" and log the length

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, please post it in comments section

Comment: Yes I'm shure. New elements fit the my selector. It's strange for me.

Comment: It is css path before ajax modified
`div#aList.block ul.noStyle li div#agent14209.alListElement`
after
`div#aList.block ul.noStyle li div#agent14210.alListElement`